# Is there a callback for ng-bind-html-unsafe in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angularjs-directive

I would like to remove some of the elements that are brought into the DOM by this...

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="whatever"></div>
```

I wrote a function that will remove the elements, but I need a way to trigger the function after `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is complete.  Is there a callback for `ng-bind-html-unsafe` or a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

ng-bind-html-unsafe has been removed from the current version (1.2+) of angular.  I would recommend using the $sanitize service in the new version of angular.  You'll need to include the sanitize library and add it to your module.

That way you can do whatever you want once the sanitize operation is complete and not worry about a callback.

A quick and dirty implementation:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <div>{{sanitized}}</div>
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngSanitize'])
      .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$sanitize', function($scope, $sanitize) {
        $scope.sanitized = $sanitize('someTextFromSomeSource');
        // Do whatever you want here with the cleaned up text
      }])
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move the html in your demo to a `directive`:

```
<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="whatever"></div>
```

in the directive I would manipulate the html based on my needs, I am here basing this on an assumption since I am not sure how often or how `whatever` variable is being updated so the generic solution will be a `$watch` listener over this variable like this:

```
$scope.$watch('whatever',function(newValue,oldValue, scope){
     //do something
});
```

All this code in my new directive, probably you will want to use the `postLink` function

Here is [the Documentation from Angular](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) about this.

> Post-linking function
>       Executed after the child elements are linked. It is safe to do DOM transformation in the post-linking function.

Comment: The content is static, but includes references to external CSS files.  I am attempting to remove those references, with something like... `querySelectorAll('[rel="stylesheet"]')` so I just need to know after its loaded the first time.

Comment: You don't manipulate html in your controller that is not a correct practice the directive has what you need. It is what is recommended in angular.

Comment: Will the directive execute on the element before or after `ng-bind-html-unsafe` is complete?

Comment: here is a plunker demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/c8WVtojWGVRAyEu0iLuW?p=preview try extending it with your code it will give us a better idea how to help you